# Apex Nested Map Returns NULL

Tags: apex, map

I have the following issue:

I've declared a nested map in a trigger:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, String>> financeOppToReopenBuyerToSupplierMap = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

A quick debug of the map shows the following:

```
14:13:50:068 USER_DEBUG [83]|DEBUG|{0019E00000UOxAhQAL={0019E00000UOxAiQAL=Sample Text}}
```

Which is what I expect to see.

The I do a financeOppToReopenBuyerToSupplierMap.get('0019E00000UOxAhQAL') which returns the inner Map:

```
14:13:50:069 USER_DEBUG [88]|DEBUG|{0019E00000UOxAiQAL=Sample Text}
```

Again this is what I except to see.

However when I try to get the '0019E00000UOxAiQAL' value from the inner map. I always get

```
14:16:52:107 FATAL_ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

What am I missing here? All the values are present in the map however it still returns null.

EDIT:

This is how I'am building the map:

```
 if(financeOppToReopenBuyerToSupplierMap.containsKey(acr.Buyer_Parent_Account__c)) {
    financeOppToReopenBuyerToSupplierMap.get(acr.Buyer_Parent_Account__c).put(acr.Supplier_Parent_Account__c, 'Sample Text');
  }
  else {
    financeOppToReopenBuyerToSupplierMap.put(acr.Buyer_Parent_Account__c, new Map<String, String>{acr.Supplier_Parent_Account__c => 'Sample Text'});
}
```

acr is the for loop variable for the custom object that I'am iterating over.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code on how you are building the map and reading from it ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I've updated the description

Comment: but how do you read from it? Can Can you try to use your map with Ids instead of strings? That may be an issue (Id-> string converted in different ways in different places). Otherwise, issue is somewhere else and its hadr to find without full code

Comment: @kurunve I did try replacing the String to an Id but there's no difference. Its odd that system.debug shows all the values however when trying to access them it throws null. If i do system.debug(map) it shows correctly but if i do system.debug(map.keyset()) throws a null exception as well. I'll try to upload the whole piece if I can later.